# How to install PgAdmin3 version 1.20.0 in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: command-line, apt, software-installation, ppa, repository

I try to install using PPA

First, I add a link to a file repository source.list directory the /etc/apt/sources.list

```
$ Sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list


 deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/pitti/postgresql/ubuntu precise play

 deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/pitti/postgresql/ubuntu precise play
```

Secondly I did update the repository with the command

```
$ Sudo apt-get update
```

although there is an error

```
: W: GPG error: precise http://ppa.launchpad.net Release: The following signatures could not be verified Because The public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 99B656EA8683D8A2
```

I added a way to overcome the apt-key, create a folder Key1 contains the code on the link below
[code key1](http://keyserver.ubuntu.com:11371/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0x99B656EA8683D8A2)

then I run the command

```
$ Sudo apt-key add / directory / key1
```

succeed

I tried to update the back third repository

```
$ Sudo apt-get update
```

succeed

four I try to run the following command to install pgadmin3 vs. 1.20.0

```
$ Sudo apt-get install pgadmin3
```

yet installed fixed vs. 1.18.0
how do I fix it?

Comment: About "broken packages" or "stable solution", see  **[this similar question](http://askubuntu.com/q/715048/439867)**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That is because, as [mentioned](https://launchpad.net/~pitti/+archive/ubuntu/postgresql) in the PPA page, the PPA is deprecated and will NOT receive ANY UPDATES any more. The 'latest' version available in that PPA is 1.18.1-1.

If you want the latest version, checkout the [repository](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt) maintained by The PostgreSQL Global Development Group (PGDG). In short,

Create /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list and put the following contents:

```
deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ precise-pgdg main
```

Import repository key, update and install the packages:

```
sudo apt-get install wget ca-certificates
wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.4 pgadmin3
```

There is also a shell [script](https://alioth.debian.org/scm/loggerhead/pkg-postgresql/postgresql-common/trunk/download/head:/apt.postgresql.org.s-20130224224205-px3qyst90b3xp8zj-1/apt.postgresql.org.sh) that will automate repository setup.

Refer [documentation](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt) for more information.

Comment: Thank for your tutorial, but why when I repeat the simulation OS Ubuntu in VirtualBox fails? All no errors such as tutorial you give

Answer (score 2):

Why do you use Precise repositories in Trusty? `pgadmin3` is in the Ubuntu repositories for Trusty and so on.

Therefore remove the lines

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/pitti/postgresql/ubuntu precise play
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/pitti/postgresql/ubuntu precise play
```

from your `sources.list` and install with

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pgadmin3
```

---

To install version `1.20.0~beta2-1` you need at least Vivid or another PPA:

```
wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ trusty-pgdg main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/postgresql.list'
```

Check with

```
% apt-cache policy pgadmin3
pgadmin3:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.20.0-1.pgdg14.04+1
  Version table:
     1.20.0-1.pgdg14.04+1 0
        500 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ trusty-pgdg/main i386 Packages
```

And install

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall pgadmin3
```

Comment: because I followed the tutorial on the following link [PostgreSQL backports for stable Ubuntu releases](https://launchpad.net/~pitti/+archive/ubuntu/postgresql) ,
it is already outdated link

Comment: I want to install that version 1.20.0 pgadmin for support on postgresql-9.4, can't directly use

$ sudo apt-get install pgadmin3