# broken packages with PgAdmin3 version 1.20 in Ubuntu 14 LTS

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, dependencies

My `pgadmin3` was perfect, working with PostgreSQL 9.3 (pg9.3)... Them I [upgraded to pg9.4](https://medium.com/@tk512/upgrading-postgresql-from-9-3-to-9-4-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts-2b4ddcd26535#.x5oqmc20n)... And start the problems... Old pgAdmin3  not runs with new pg9.4, so pgAdmin3 needs also  upgrade.

With pg9.4 working (perfect) I checked `apt-cache policy pgadmin3` and see that candidate 1.20 was there, so I remove old pgadmin3 and install  new pgadmin3... PROBLEM:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 pgadmin3 : Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.9) but ...
            Depends: ....
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So, **what I can do now?**

---

### NOTES

Complete step-by-step and messagens,

1. All was working and I check,

   ```
   apt-cache policy pgadmin3
   pgadmin3:
     Installed: 1.18.1-2
     Candidate: 1.20.0-1.pgdg14.10+1
     Version table:
      1.20.0-1.pgdg14.10+1 0
        500 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ utopic-pgdg/main amd64 Packages
      *** 1.18.1-2 0
        500 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
   ```
2. The `sudo apt-get remove pgadmin3` was ok. Now the check changes, `apt-cache policy pgadmin3`

   ```
   pgadmin3:
    Installed: (none)
    Candidate: 1.20.0-1.pgdg14.10+1
    Version table:
      1.20.0-1.pgdg14.10+1 0
        500 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ utopic-pgdg/main amd64 Packages
      1.18.1-2 0
        500 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
   ```
3. The bug arrives here, after `sudo apt-get update` (ok), I do

   ```
   sudo apt-get install pgadmin3`

   Reading package lists... Done
   Building dependency tree       
   Reading state information... Done
   Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
   requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
   distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
   or been moved out of Incoming.
   The following information may help to resolve the situation:

   The following packages have unmet dependencies:
    pgadmin3 : Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.9) but 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04 is to be installed
               Depends: libwxbase3.0-0 (>= 3.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libwxgtk3.0-0 (>= 3.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
   E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
   ```

PS: the question [How to install PgAdmin3 version 1.20.0 in Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/q/664110/439867) is about the same subject, but is poluted and not solve 2016's  problems.

---

[This link](http://www.rogerpence.com/2015/01/02/install-postgres-9-4-on-ubuntu/) says

> There isn’t yet an apt-get package for pgAdmin 1.20.0. Step four above installs pgAdmin 1.18.0 which works with Postgres 9.4 but doesn’t provide 9.4-specific features. If you want to install pgAdmin 1.20.0 you currently [need to install it from source](http://pgadmin.org/download/).

But even its "*(Update: on 6 January, Ubuntu’s automatic software updates upgraded pgAdmin to 1.20.0.)*" **is wrong**, because `apt-get` not works as I showed.

Comment: `pgadmin3 (= 1.20.0-1.pgdg14.10+1)`  needs `libstdc++6 (>= 4.9)` and this package isn't available for Trusty.

Comment: @A.B.  no way to fix `libstdc` in LTS?  How to back the old version that was (not perfect but)   working?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install pgadmin3=1.18.1-2`

Comment: You could try the PPA `ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test` to install `libstdc++6 4.9`

Comment: @A.B. My fear is to let this wrong PPA to other installations ... Can I use PPA only to this update, them remove it?

Comment: Yes, add the PPA, install the package and remove the PPA

Comment: @A.B.  Hum ... I am not an expert... I need UBUNTU LTS, LST, stable (!), so `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test` will destroy stability... How to **undo** this adiction of  `ppa/test` after   pgadmin upgrade?

Comment: If you need a stable system don't add the PPA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pgadmin3 (= 1.20.0-1.pgdg14.10+1)` needs `libstdc++6 (>= 4.9)` and this package isn't available for Trusty and as you say in your comments

> I need Ubuntu LTS, LST, stable (!)

don't add a PPA with higher versions of `libstdc++6`. These packages are an integral part of the system.

Install `pgadmin3 (= 1.18.1-2)` again

```
sudo apt-get install pgadmin3=1.18.1-2
```

and wait some days for Ubuntu 16.04, the next LTS release.

Comment: Thanks a lot,  about all explanations (!). Well it seems that it is a problem without solution for 14.04 LTS (even for future UBUNTU 14 upgrades?)... Accepting as "most helpful"... Ops, you also show me the "install back", that is a solution.

Comment: There is always a solution, unless stability is very important.

Answer (score 3):

I also faced this problem and after spending a whole day I found this result. These commands given below to install pgadmin3 worked in my Ubuntu.

Add the repository:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ $(lsb_release -cs)-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list'
```

Install their key:

```
wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
```

Install pgadmin3:

```
sudo apt-get install pgadmin3
```